MLKit & Cocoapods in Multiplatform - Incompatible Interfaces
Image Type Mismatch in Kotlin Multiplatform Project with MLKit
I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Project using Kotlin 2 and Xcode 15.4, integrating MLKit for barcode scanning. I'm encountering a type mismatch error when trying to use the resultsInImage function of MLKBarcodeScanner.
I have an image implementing cocoapods.MLKitVision.MLKCompatibleImageProtocol, but the resultsInImage function requires objcnames.protocols.MLKCompatibleImageProtocol.
I've tried using both GMLImage and MLKVisionImage, but neither works. The compiler gives me this error:
Argument type mismatch: actual type is 'cocoapods.MLKitVision.MLKVisionImage', but 'objcnames.protocols.MLKCompatibleImageProtocol' was expected.

However, MLKVisionImage does implement cocoapods.MLKitVision.MLKCompatibleImageProtocol.
Here's my setup:

In build.gradle.kts, I've imported the libraries using:
pod("MLKitVision")
pod("MLKitBarcodeScanning")

(The official recommended pod("GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning") didn't work)

My imports in the iosMain file:
import cocoapods.MLKitBarcodeScanning.MLKBarcodeScanner
import cocoapods.MLKitVision.MLKVisionImage


The problematic code:
val barCodeResults = barcodeScanner.resultsInImage(MLKVisionImage(didOutputSampleBuffer))

Android Studio shows: "Type mismatch. Required: MLKCompatibleImageProtocol Found: MLKVisionImage"


I've tried casting MLKVisionImage to MLKCompatibleImageProtocol of the objcnames.protocols package, but that didn't work either.
Interestingly, when I try the same in a Swift file within the same project, it works fine, suggesting that the package installation is correct.
Why doesn't this work in the Kotlin iosMain part? Why does the interface appear in the package objcnames.protocols?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

I rebuild the project and used the cast
as objcnames.protocols.MLKCompatibleImageProtocol
and it worked :)
still MLKVisionImage and GMLImage should yield conformative instances, but they don't.
